# Python: How Do I Read A Single Letter From A Specific Line From A TXT

Tags: python

I'm new to python, so this is probably easy. But I'm trying to print (from a txt file) the first letter of the first line, then the first letter in the second, etc. If possible can you add a while function that lets the program know to stop doing this when the line it is checking has nothing in it.

I'm sorry that there's no code I've written to help, none of it I've made looks particularly helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Here's how to go about it: Read the file line by line in your while loop (I recommend you use `<file>.readline()`). If the line length is non-zero, extract the first character with `line[0]`. Then go on to the next line.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps like this:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line[0]
```

If you wish to break out of the loop when you encounter an empty line then you do this:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip('\n') == '':
            break
        print line[0]
```

Or perhaps a more Pythonic way to test for empty string:

```
if not line.rstrip('\n'):
    break
```

Comment: No need to increment index. Incrementing will give you 1st char of 1st line, 2nd char of 2nd line, ...

Comment: @IceArdor Sorry, I mis-read the question.

Comment: Thanks to IceArdor, Alko and Guy for pointing out my errors. Hangs head in shame ...

Comment: I wonder how the OP defines "has nothing in it".  If he means a single newline then `if line == '\n':` is also a possibility.  If he means only whitespace then `if not line.strip():` would be best.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            print line[0]
        else:
            break
```